# How can I use South's DataMigration to change the storage backend of Django model ImageField instance?

Tags: django, migration, django-south, imagefield, django-storage

I'm trying to migrate some models ImageFields to using the `S3BotoStorage` storage backend from `django-storages`.  As part of this process I've changed my Model's ImageField  declaration to include the `storage=instance_of_s3botostorage` argument, and new instances of my Model that save an image to the ImageField attribute now get stored in S3 - as intended.

I tried to move existing model instances over to storing their data in S3, too, so wrote a South DataMigration like this:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    "upload ImageField file to S3 if it's not already in there"
    for mymodel in orm.MyModel.objects.all():
        if mymodel.logo_image and not isinstance(mymodel.logo_image.storage, S3BotoStorage):
            print "uploading %s to S3" % mymodel.logo_image
            file_contents = ContentFile(mymodel.logo_image.read())
            mymodel.logo_image.save(mymodel.logo_image.name, file_contents)
            mymodel.save()
```

but this clearly doesn't have the intended effect because the image file is simply saved using the old `storage` backend - which makes sense considering save() is actually a method of the `FieldFile` belonging to the `FileField`

So, how to move/change file storage on an instance of a model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, turns out the particular storage used for files is not stored in the database.  'migration' is simply a matter of changing the Model definition then, outside of using the storage subsystem API, simply upload files into the new storage locations.

Comment: Go ahead and accept this answer. It'll help those who come after you.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a bit? I am facing exactly same issue.

Comment: @neokya so, change the model definition to reference the new storage backend you wish to use, then (using some other tool) copy data from your original file storage to the new file storage (preserving paths, of course).

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly what you are saying. I wrote a small script to copy files here and there, which looks fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at a system more like this for your problem. http://github.com/seanbrant/django-queued-storage